# Notification Vibration Bug on Galaxy Nexus?

Tags: notifications, vibration, samsung-galaxy-nexus

My Galaxy Nexus running 4.0.2 does not vibrate for any notifications while in "vibrate" mode. Haptic feedback works, and the phone vibrates when I receive phone calls, but not for notifications. The global vibrate setting under "Sound" in the menu is set to "Always", and individual apps like Gmail, Messaging, etc. have vibrate set to "Always".

Any help appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the phone to two different Verizon stores, talked to phone support, and even got a replacement- to no avail. *Finally I installed the Sound Manager app and set it to "Vibrate Whenever Possible".* This fixed the problem!

Answer (score 2):

There is a separate vibrate setting in the menu for sms messaging under Settings.

Comment: This didn't help my problem. Both of those settings were set to "Vibrate Always"

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the [Llama app](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.kebab.Llama) then removing it. For some reason it fixes this, I had the same problem. There is a issue on the [tracker](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=23300#c8) that could help.